# Go generator function to create values satisifying an interface

Tags: go

I'm trying to generalise over value types in some code. I need to make a whole bunch of the values and then operate over them. the API looks approximately as follows:

```
type Foo interface {
  A(string) error
}

func Run(foo_gen func () (Foo, error)) {
  ...
}
```

On the other side I have:

```
type bar struct {
  ...
}

func (bar Bar) A (s string) {
  ...
}

func main() {
  foo_gen := func () (bar, error) {
  return bar{}, nil
  }
  mypackage.Run(foo_gen)
}
```

This is failing with an error saying:

```
cannot use foo_gen (type func () (bar, error)) as type func() (mypackage.Foo, error) in argument to mypackage.Run
```

I'm fairly new to go so there likely is some basic thing I am missing. What I was expecting was that the compiler would try to explicitly cast `bar` to `Foo` by matching method types (similar to a record subtyping relation), however this doesn't appear to be the case?

Comment: No, it is not the case. The signatures must match verbatim.

Comment: @Adrian How do the sockets etc work? bc they seem to export a Union of the type signatures?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to, can you point me at docs showing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The engineering reason for this error is given in @kostix's comment. At a type level this is what is occurring.

The issue is that the go compiler can't lift a `func () (bar, error))` to a `func () (Foo, error)` because in general go values are not [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

The result of this is that there are several ways to solve this.

One is to change the return type of the function:

```
foo_gen := func () (Foo, error) {
  return bar{}, nil
}
```

This works because it is able to lift the `bar{}` value to a `Foo` value easily.

Another approach if I wasn't able to change the generator function (this will also work for channels etc) is to wrap the generator in another function:

```
bar_gen := func () (bar, error){
  return bar{}, nil
}
  
foo_gen := func() (Foo, error){
  foobar, err := bar_gen()
  return foobar, err
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The explanation might be surprising but is actually simple.

`foo_gen` is defined as `func () (Foo, error)`, so the first returned value has the type `Foo`, which is an interface.

A value of *any* interface type is a `struct` with two pointers: to the *concrete* value actually held in that interface value and to (some internal object representing) its type. A classic and very good (if maybe a bit rusty) explanation of how interface values are implemented is [this](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces).

The actual function you've tried to match the signature we've just discussed returns a value of type `Bar` as its first returned value. That type is a `struct` type, which has nothing to do with the interface value expected by the original signature.
In other words, to make your function returning a value of type `Bar` satisfy the signature which expects a value of interface type `Foo`, the compiler would have to generate code which would copy the returned `Bar` to the heap and synthesize a value of `Foo` from it. While probably doable, that would be too implicit and might be otherwise surprising.

The compiler disallows assigning of a slice `[]T` to a variable of type `[]interface{}` for [pretty much the same reason](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface).

Comment: That is really rather interesting! I was looking for approximately that documentation and couldn't find it. Does this mean that it is impossible for an approach such as this to work?

Comment: Additionally this is mostly the correct answer, however the actual fix for the problem is to change the return type of the function. (The actual issue being that it can't convert a `(unit -> bar)` type into a `(unit -> Foo)` type but the compiler can do that conversion inside the generator function, ie its a subtyping issue)

Comment: @Cjen1, Go cannot have "subtyping issues" because it has no subtyping. Go has OOP but the approach to it which Go implements does not contain the concept of inheritance. At all. There is no inheritance in Go. This wrong mental model may be precisely what makes you confused about the issue at hand.

Comment: A way to solve the problem at all is simply to make the concrete `foo_gen` (defined in `main`) has `Foo` as the type of its first return value.

Comment: Yep I understand what you mean regarding go not having subtyping, but the ducktyping seems to only apply to raw values but not to anything derived (functions, slices etc) which means that functions are not covariant in their return type which was what I was trying to say.

Comment: @Cjen1, Do you mean [this](https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types) FAQ entry? ;-) I admit, it supposedly talks about a less general issue, but still.

Comment: I'm not buying this. The compiler wraps concrete values into interface values all the time during assignment, even implicitly in assignments of function parameters or return values (think about any function that returns an error). The impossible slice conversation is justified with different memory layouts, and not hiding a potentially very expensive conversion, but that does not apply to single values. The absence of covariance has nothing to with this.

Comment: @Peter, don't forget that when you return an `error` you do not return your concrete (pointer to a) value but rather construct and return a value of `error`, quite explicitly. The thing which makes Go's interfaces special is that in "more conventional" PLs declaring a value of some interface type actually creates a pointer-sized slot, and the compiler "knows" how to find the actual type's methods (through VTBLs). In a Go program, given duck typing, the set of types actually implementing any given interface is unbounded, …

Comment: @Peter, …and that's why Go's values of interface types have more complex runtime representation — they are more dynamic, by their nature. So while in "more conventional" PLs a value of interface type is just a pointer with a bounded set of types of pointed-to values which can be assigned to it, in Go, a value of interface type does not have the same memory layout than values it can "hold". I'm not sure you can implement covariance with this model as it would probably create more problems than solve. (Sadly, I am not a language theorist/designer though.)

Comment: @kostix for reference covariance just refers to the direction of subtyping. So (from a language theory perspective) duck typing is a form of subtyping where we have a relation `bar :> Foo` covariance is then just that parameterised types (not the right phrasing but decent enough) subtype. So if channels were covariant: `chan bar :> chan Foo` and `chan bar` can be given to functions requiring `chan Foo`. Contravariance then is `chan Foo :> chan bar` which is much less widely used. You could get covariance in Go but it would require a level of indirection which would be painful and unexpected.

Comment: @kostix, "Don't forget that when you return an error you do not return your concrete (pointer to a) value". Yes, of course you do. You cannot create a non-nil interface value without assignment. The compiler *must* routinely generate code that initializes interface "tuples". https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.15.1/src/errors/errors.go#L59